# Ignore some of the properties during Json.NET serializing but required on others

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am using the Json.Net to serialize an object.
This is the code:

```
 var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize, Formatting.Indented,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore });
```

The DefaultValueHandling  set to ignore so the result string do not contain properties with default values.

In the Serialized class, there is a unique property that should be on the result string anyway,
So i'm using an attribute to make sure the property will be there:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "componentMainVersion", Required = Required.Always)] 
    public ushort Version { get; set; }
```

The problem is that the property do not generated to the string.
And i'm getting an exception when deserializing the string back to object:

> "Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaException: 'Required properties are
> missing from object: Version..."

How can I make sure the property will be in the result string anyway (default value or not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "componentMainVersion", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)] 
    public ushort Version { get; set; }
```

Required is a different property which makes sure that value for the property is required always